# iphone client side mac server TCP /IP

Tags: iphone

I'm doing a typical client - server application, where the server is 
going to be a MAC (the server also uses AsynSocket) and the clients 
are some iPhones/iPod Touch/iPads and I want to  know how can i send 
messages between de iPhones for example. 
I can send information to the server, and it answers me correctly, but 
I don't know how to sen a message between user1 - server - user2 and 
then that the user2 answers the message :S 
Can you help me? is it possible to to that using AsyncSocket? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have direct communication between the clients, this isn't a client - server application anymore.

For *Peer-to-Peer* communication I suggest to use **GameKit**. Create your `GKSession` with mode `GKSessionModePeer` and the same session ID on both clients so that they can communicate.

Read about *Peer-to-Peer Connectivity* in the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html).